# Unique key not working

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I have a table cars, which gets populated with the joined data of table cars1 and cars2.
The schema looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `cars` (
   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `uniqueid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
   UNIQUE KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

However, I have duplicate entries for the uniqueid field in my table:

```
 ID     UNIQUEID     NAME
 1      1            Mercedes
 2      2            Audi
 3      2            Chevrolet
```

The data get's populated in that table from cars1 and cars2 with simple INSERT IGNORE INTO SELECT FROM statement.

How is this even possible? Could it be that the index of the table is corrupt? I came across that duplicate rows by doing:

```
 SELECT uniqueid, COUNT(uniqueid) FROM cars GROUP BY uniqueid HAVING(COUNT(uniqueid)>1);
```

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `uniqueid` field is `VARCHAR(10)`, it means it can contain `'1'`, `'1 '` or `'1     '`, and all these values looks the same, but they aren't the same.

Make the field `uniqueid` INT; and problem will dissapear.

Comment: What if I can't do that, because the uniqueid field contains also id's like 'abcd'?

Comment: I can suggest you to update the table - to trim strings: UPDATE cars SET uniqueid = TRIM(uniqueid).